# Find out which function(s) from certain package were used

Tags: r, package

Is there a way to find out which functions from a certain package were called within the current session?

(I'm sourcing various scripts in varying orders and would like to stop using any `plyr` function due to the loading-`plyr`-after-`dplyr`-problem but it seems a bit tedious to go through all scripts to find out which `plyr`-functions I am actually using.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`list.functions.in.file`](http://search.r-project.org/library/NCmisc/html/list.functions.in.file.html) from the [`{NCmisc}`package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NCmisc/index.html) seems to do what you're looking for. It returns a list of all functions used within a script and returns them separated by the package they're from.

An example: When you run the function over this dummy code (saved as an R script) which runs a few examples with functions from `{ggplot2}`, `{dplyr}`, and `{tidyr}`...

```
# ggplot2 examples
library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point()
qplot(data = diamonds, x = carat, y = price, color = color)

#dplyr examples
library(dplyr)
filter(mtcars, cyl == 8)
select_(iris, "Petal.Length")

#tidyr examples
library(tidyr)
gather(iris, key = flower_att, value = measurement,
       Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)

df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b"), y = c(3, 4), z = c(5, 6))
df %>% spread(x, y) %>% gather(x, y, a:b, na.rm = TRUE)
```

you get the following list as output:

```
$`c("package:dplyr", "package:stats")`
[1] "filter"

$`package:base`
[1] "c"          "data.frame" "library"   

$`package:dplyr`
[1] "select_"

$`package:ggplot2`
[1] "aes"        "geom_point" "ggplot"     "qplot"     

$`package:tidyr`
[1] "gather" "spread"
```

Comment: Perhaps that function does not work on .Rnw files (for knitr, LaTeX)?  Error in parse(filename, keep.source = TRUE) : 
  ~/R/Projects/Baseball/baseball.Rnw:1:1: unexpected input
1: \
    ^
In addition: Warning message:
In list.functions.in.file("~/R/Projects/Baseball/baseball.Rnw") :
  expecting *.R file, will try to proceed

Comment: Yes, it also doesn't currently work with R-Markdown (.Rmd) files as far as I could see when testing it.

Comment: wow! this function `NCmisc::list.functions.in.file` is brilliant. Needed it for a long time. Discovered it today only. Thanks @ab